# Как сделать курсивом весь английский текст в документе?

Tags: latex

Пишу диплом на LaTeX, но не пользуюсь готовыми классами, поскольку у университета свои стандарты.

В этом стандарте есть очень интересное требование - ВСЕ английские надписи должны быть обозначены курсивом все зависимости от того, где они написаны (обычный текст, заголовки, подписи к рисункам и т.д.). При этом должно соблюдаться форматирование стиля (т.е. если заголовок с английским словом жирный, то нужное слово должно быть жирным курсивом).

Я уверен, что это как-то можно автоматически организовать в LaTeX, чтобы каждый раз не выделять английский язык курсивом вручную, но я пока информацию, как это сделать, не находил.

Используемый дистрибутив: TeXLive

Используемый компилятор: XeLaTeX

UPD:

Нашёл, в какую сторону копать по этому вопросу - все дело в пакете `fontspec` (который подключается вместе с `polyglossia`). Именно через него нужно настроить какие-то опции для шрифта, но как связать шрифт с языком - я пока не догадался. Дело в том, что шрифт используется один для обоих языков, но для английского нужно именно курсивное написание.

Пока что сделал такое костыльное решение:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14bp,a4paper]{scrreprt}

% Подключение пакетов
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка

% Установка параметров для документа
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}  %% устанавливает главный язык документа
\setotherlanguage{english} %% объявляет второй язык документа
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

% Команды для документа
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textlang{english}{\textit{#1}}} %весь английский язык - курсивом

\begin{document}
    Привет, мир!
    
    \eng{Hello, world!}
    
    \textlang{english}{Hello,world!}
    
    {\bfseries \eng{Hello, world!}}
    
    {\bfseries \textlang{english}{Hello,world!}}
    
\end{document}
```

Хотелось бы найти решение получше, через опции пакетов.